# Google sheet transpose yahoo finance data and ignore multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

gurus,

I am trying to get yahoo finance quote page info into google sheet. What bothers me is the earning date, which could be a range:

[image]

The following code works, but the earning date will return into 4 lines with the React notes

```
=transpose(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",B7,"?p=",B7),"//tr//td[last()]"))
```

Is there anyway I can consolidate the data from O8-O12 into O7? Or just simply ignore the O8-O12 data in this example. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a query formula as well and limit results to 1:

```
=QUERY(transpose(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",B7,"?p=",B7),"//tr//td[last()]")),"LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: That's great :)